# Which Markdown editor does Reddit use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, markdown, reddit

The new redesign of Reddit features a really slick WYSIWYG/Markdown editor. Screenshots:

[image: Fancy Pants]

Once clicking on "Switch to markdown":

[image: Markdown]

Is this an open-source library available for implementation, or is this entirely an internal Reddit-only solution?

On another note, I've been comparing a whole bunch of Markdown editors, and can't seem to find anything that works really well with React. SimpleMDE isn't bad, but its last commit was two and a half years ago, and it has no official React bindings either.

What would be my best alternative for direct implementation into a React app?

Comment: I've used [react-rte](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte) before. It has an official React bindings and components. It's pure text editor though, without table/image/video features

Comment: Any luck? Same problem

Comment: @parsecer Nope :( pretty sure it's proprietary

Comment: This one looks alright: https://www.cssscript.com/simple-extendable-wysiwyg-markdown-editor-mditor/ and demo: https://www.cssscript.com/demo/simple-extendable-wysiwyg-markdown-editor-mditor/

Comment: Everything after "On another note" should be moved to a new question. I will upvote and answer if you do!